# Determining whether or not previous Activity can handle multiple Fragments in current orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am developing an app that is very similar to the typical newsreader app. I have a Listview in a fragment on the left side of the screen and the right side shows the details of the selected item if we're in landscape view. Otherwise the details fragment is shown in its own Activity. I have this working just fine.

However there is one caveat: I only want it to behave this way on larger screen sizes (probably only tablets but that's subject to change). On smaller devices I want to see only the the Listview fragment and launch the details fragment in its own activity no matter the orientation. I also have this working.

The problem I currently have is in the Details Activity and how to determine when to finish() and return back to the previous activity to show the fragments side by side. I have the following code that works for larger devices but doesn't allow smaller devices to view this activity and thus the details fragment at all:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
     Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
       finish();
       return;
    }
```

How can I determine that going back to the previous activity will allow the fragments to be displayed side by side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eureka! My solution is to provide an alternate layout for the Details Activity that was empty. After I inflate the layout I can check to see if the fragment I am expecting is in the layout and if it isn't then I finish().

details_view.xml in /res/layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
   <fragment
         android:name="com.website.DetailsFragment"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/details_fragment"
         android:layout_weight="75">
   </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

details_view.xml in /res/layout-[screen size]
This one is for any screen size that you do not want to display the Details fragment in its own activity in landscape mode (more or less tablets in my case).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Note: This file has an empty layout to notify
     DetailsViewActivity that we should go back to landscape
     and view the fragments side by side -->
<LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

Simply put the empty details_view.xml file in any layout directory that has the layout file that allows to show the fragments side by side.

Finally the code for DetailsViewActivity to exit if we want to go back to side by side:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.details_view);

  mDetailsView = (TopicViewFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
   .findFragmentById(R.id.details_fragment);

  // We can handle the fragments side by side in the previous activity
  // so lets go back there
  if ((mDetailsView == null || !mDetailsView.isInLayout()) &&
   getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
   Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
     finish();
     return;
  }
```

I would have liked a little less duplication of data but this solution isn't bad. It only forces you to copy one extra layout file into the same directory that you have the side by side fragments layout file. Not too bad really.

Comment: Cool.  You can answer your own question and get points.  There's even a badge for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following also work without the the usage of an empty layout.

```
package de.vogella.android.fragments;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.res.Configuration;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.widget.TextView;

   public class DetailActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Need to check if Activity has been switched to landscape mode
    // If yes, finished and go back to the start Activity
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.details_activity_layout);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String s = extras.getString("value");
        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
        view.setText(s);
    }
}
```

}